# Just able to traverse the 1st sub directory of a given directory but not all

Tags: python

Writing a program which traverse all the directory and files in it of a given Directory without using "os.walk", but I am able to traverse only the 1st sub directory of a give directory not the all.

```
import os

sub_dir = []

fi = []

def print_directory_contents(sPath):

    di = os.listdir(sPath)
    for y in di:
        if "." in y:
            fi.append(y)
        else:
            sub_dir.append(y)

    print("path : ", sPath)
    print("dir : ", sub_dir)
    print("file : ", fi)
    print("--------------------------------\n")
    sub_dir.clear()
    fi.clear()
    # print(di)

    print(di)
    for x in di:
        print(di)
        if os.path.isdir('{}/{}'.format(sPath, x)):
            os.chdir('{}/{}'.format(sPath, x))
            new_spath = os.getcwd()
            print_directory_contents(new_spath)

check_dir = input()

print_directory_contents(check_dir)
```

Comment: You are reinventing [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), poorly.

Comment: You're question is only code...

Comment: made changes check again.

Comment: Thanks @SergeBallesta problem has been solved, now the question can be closed :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call your function recursively as:

```
import os

def print_directory_contents(sPath):
    print sPath
    for dir in os.listdir(sPath):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(sPath, dir)):
            print_directory_contents(os.path.join(sPath, dir))
```

Comment: I know i can do this with os.walk, but i got a challange to do this without using "os.walk"

Comment: then call `print_directory_contents(sPath)` recursively with sPath being sub directories

Comment: it is entirely traversing only the 1st sub directory of a given directory even after using print_directory_contents(sPath)

Comment: edited one should work

Comment: thanks man, this solution solved my problem